# $\pi_n(X^n,X^{n-1})$

Tags: algebraic-topology

While helping someone solve a problem, I made the assumption that $\pi_n(X^n,X^{n-1})$ is free abelian where $X^k$ is the $k$-skeleton of a connected CW-complex, since the quotient $X^n/X^{n-1}$ is a wedge of spheres.  I began to question whether my assumption is valid.  According to Blakers-Massey $\pi_k(X^n,X^{n-1})\rightarrow \pi_k(X^n/X^{n-1})$ is an isomorphism for all $k<n$ and an epimorphism for $k=n$.  But, that doesn't quite do it.  Is there a way to prove my assumption?

Comment: Use the Hurewicz isomorphism.